# Can't run dotnet in shell file but can in terminal?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 and I'm fairly green to Linux systems.

I'm trying to run a shell script that I wrote, which is fairly simple:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
dotnet /some/file.dll
```

The script is located in `<root>/var/www/`. It would be run by calling `systemctl start my-program.service`.

But when I run it I get the error message `3: dotnet: not found`. This doesn't make a whole lot of sense because I can run the `dotnet` command in my terminal no problem, and when I try to run it from `<root>/snap/bin/dotnet` in the terminal it also works just fine.

The installation of the dotnet sdk is located at `<root>/snap/bin/dotnet` so I thought I just needed to add that to my `PATH` which I did. It looks like this:

`PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`

It was added using the `export` command.

I even restarted the server afterwards, but still to no avail. The Shell file keeps giving me that error.

How would I fix this?

Comment: You do not mention from where the shell script will be running. A shell prompt where `dotnet`  is also available? Or perhaps something like a cron job or whatever? You also do not mention where and how you attempted to add `/snap/bin`  to your path. Please update your question with this information.

Comment: Have updated it now.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it you are trying to run this script as a systemd service.

Systemd services can't make too many assumptions in what environment they are run. More specifically they don't have access to the PATH you define in your user-session, because they don't run in your user-session context. They will run in the system context.
The easiest way to do this is just to specify the full path to the dotnet executable in the shell script. That removes the dependency on the PATH.

Comment: I have also tried `/snap/bin/dotnet`. Got the same message.

Comment: Are you sure the command is actually /snap/bin/dotnet ? Because you wouldn't add the command itself to the PATH, but the FOLDER in which the command resides. But in the script you would use the full path of the command. That would make the command itself /snap/bin/dotnet/dotnet or something similar. (I don't have a Linux system with snap at my disposal so I can't verify myself.)

Comment: I have tried it in the terminal directly, and `/snap/bin/dotnet` works because dotnet is not a folder, it's the literal file that is needed to run the dotnet cli tool.

Comment: Your service may be starting before _snapd_ is done. Maybe `After=snapd.service` could help.

Comment: @DanielB That would make a lot of sense. I'll take your word for it. I try to avoid dealing with systemd as much as possible (I really don't like it) and I never used snap, so I have no idea about such dependencies.

Comment: @DanielB So in my service file in the Unit Block I put in After=snapd.service ?